# Optaplanner optimization

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to apply optaplanner to my project, such as picking order path calculation. When there are many order items, the calculation speed is very slow. I want to know how to improve the calculation speed,When the order items are more than 200, the calculation speed is particularly slow, and I only add constraints. I defined a selectionsorterweightfactory, but the debug doesn't seem to work.

```
private Constraint requiredNumberOfBuckets(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
return constraintFactory
    .forEach(TrolleyStep.class)
    // raw total volume per order
    .groupBy(
        trolleyStep -> trolleyStep.getTrolley(),
        trolleyStep -> trolleyStep.getOrderItem().getOrderCode(),
        sum(trolleyStep -> trolleyStep.getOrderItem().getProduct().getCapacity()))
    // required buckets per order
    .groupBy(
        (trolley, order, orderTotalVolume) -> trolley,
        (trolley, order, orderTotalVolume) -> order,
        sum(
            (trolley, order, orderTotalVolume) ->
                calculateOrderRequiredBuckets(orderTotalVolume, trolley.getBucketCapacity())))
    // required buckets per trolley
    .groupBy(
        (trolley, order, orderTotalBuckets) -> trolley,
        sum((trolley, order, orderTotalBuckets) -> orderTotalBuckets))
    // penalization if the trolley don't have enough buckets to hold the orders
    .filter((trolley, trolleyTotalBuckets) -> trolley.getBucketNum() < trolleyTotalBuckets)
    .penalize(
        "Required number of buckets",
        HardSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD,
        (trolley, trolleyTotalBuckets) -> trolleyTotalBuckets - trolley.getBucketNum());}

private Constraint minimizeOrderSplitByTrolley(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
return constraintFactory
    .forEach(TrolleyStep.class)
    .groupBy(
        trolleyStep -> trolleyStep.getOrderItem().getOrderCode(),
        countDistinctLong(TrolleyStep::getTrolley))
    .penalizeLong(
        "Minimize order split by trolley",
        HardSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT,
        (order, trolleySpreadCount) -> trolleySpreadCount * 10000);


  private Constraint distanceToEnd(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
return constraintFactory
    .forEach(TrolleyStep.class)
    .filter(ele -> ele.getNextStep() == null)
    .penalizeLong(
        " distance to end ",
        HardSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT,
        trolleyStep -> (long) trolleyStep.distanceToLocation(OrderPickingService.end));}


private Constraint distanceToPrevious(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
return constraintFactory
    .forEach(TrolleyStep.class)
    .penalizeLong(
        " distance to previous ",
        HardSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT,
        trolleyStep ->
            (long)
                trolleyStep.distanceToLocation(
                    trolleyStep.getPreviousStandstill().getLocation()));}
```

Comment: Please share additional information, such as your constraints. Otherwise the only thing I can say is that you read the documentation: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#scoreCalculationPerformanceTricks

Comment: I added constraints, which refer to the order picking in the official document

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be the `requiredNumberOfBuckets` constraint.

Unfortunately, in the current implementation of Constraint Streams, there is no way how to make three consecutive `groupBy()`s fast. You will have to find a way around it. I'd experiment with writing a custom `ConstraintCollector` that would do the work in one `groupBy(...)`, as opposed to doing it in three steps.